# Attempting to use CustomJS in Bokeh to create interactive plot

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am trying to create an interactive plot with Bokeh on a Jupyter Notebook. I am trying to add interactivity to the plot, making it change in real time. The goal is to simply change the position of some points on a plot. I attempted using the CustomJS method, since that is what is told in the documentation.

However, this is my first experience with JavaScript, and I am not exactly sure of how I must apply JavaScript with Bokeh.
I have attempted this code:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1,0,1], y=[0,1,1]))

plot = figure(width=400, height=400)
plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

slider1 = Slider(start=0.1, end=6, value=1, step=.1, title="Escalar 1")
slider2 = Slider(start=0.1, end=6, value=1, step=.1, title="Escalar 2")

update_tamanho = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, slider1=slider1, slider2=slider2), code="""
const f1 = cb_obj.value
const f2 = cb_obj.value
const x = source.data.x
const y = source.data.y
x[0] = f1
x[2] = f1
y[1] = f2
y[2] = f2
source.data = { x, y }
""")
slider2.js_on_change('value', update_tamanho)
slider1.js_on_change('value', update_tamanho)

show(column(slider1, slider2, plot))
```

Which is an adaptation of the code in the tutorial.
The plot is shown correctly, with three dots at [1,0], [0,1] and [1,1]. The sliders are also shown correctly. However, whenever I move the sliders, the plot doesn't update. What must I do to fix this and what would be the most relevant things for learning interactive plots with Bokeh?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try source.change.emit(); in your js code after changing of your data

Comment: Thank you, it works now!
I have another question: do you know how I can change the size of an arrow interactively in Bokeh? I was able to change position of the circles on the plot, but when I try to create a similar code to change the size of an arrow, it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "size"?